# Axios post, missing grant type

Tags: axios

Getting data: `{ error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'Missing grant type' } }`

Content-Type is correct, not sure what is wrong

```
return axiosInstance({
  method: 'post',
  url: axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL + '/oauth/token',
  data: {
    "grant_type": "vapi_key",
    key: api_key
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
```

Edit: This is called via NodeJS

Comment: Could you provide network status when the request is sent in Chrome DevTools?

Comment: @Antonio This is called via NodeJS

Answer (score 10):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362) about this matter. Try this [solution](https://medium.com/@siwanyt/axios-x-www-form-urlencoded-issue-55de9564f8c0), Which suggest stringifing the data (you can  use [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) package for it) :

```
import qs from 'qs';

return axiosInstance({
  method: 'post',
  url: axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL + '/oauth/token',
  data: {
    "grant_type": "vapi_key",
    key: api_key
  },
  data: qs.stringify({
    "grant_type": "vapi_key",
    key: api_key
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  That fixed it.  I have been racking my brain.

Comment: Glad I could help :) please mark the answers for others as helpful (the green V sign)